# Cannot reload UITable from didReceiveLocalNotification

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uilocalnotification, appdelegate

My issue is that I am getting local notifications and then telling one of my VCs to updates its UITableView. However, the tableview doesn't reload. I know for a fact that all the if statement checks are passing and it is running the code. This originally made me believe it was a thread issue so I wrapped the reload in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {})`. This however doesn't work either. So if it is not a thread issues what is it? What could be causing this? Am I doing something wrong here?

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    if notification.alertBody != nil{
        if notification.alertBody!.hasSuffix("starting") || notification.alertBody!.hasSuffix("ending"){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                if topMostContoller() is SecondViewController{
                    let vc = self.tabBarController?.getVC(.Attendance) as! SecondViewController
                    vc.myTableView?.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths((vc.myTableView?.indexPathsForVisibleRows)!, withRowAnimation: .None)
    //              vc.myTableView?.reloadData() <- this doesn't work either
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
func getVC(vc:tabBarVC)->UIViewController?{
    switch vc{
    case .Home:
        return fullTabBar[0]
    case .Attendance:
        return fullTabBar[1]
    case .Location:
        return fullTabBar[2]
    case .Sign:
        return fullTabBar[3]
    case .Settings:
        return fullTabBar[4]
    }
}
```

Where fullTabBar is set in the tabBar's `viewDidLoad`.

`fullTabBar = self.viewControllers as [UIViewController]!`

`self` being the tabBar instance.

Comment: Can you print the value of `vc.myTableView` just before calling the reload?

Comment: @PhillipMills `vc = Optional(<UITableView: 0x7fef5a988a00; frame = (0 135; 768 889); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fef5e818220>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fef5bc7e810>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {768, 2728}>)`

Comment: Also other code, such as populating the array of data for the UITableView, runs but does not actually effect the objects they are supposed to. I omitted that to keep the question as simplistic as possible.

Comment: Would you mind posting your getVC code?

Comment: @OlivierWilkinson I highly doubt it's returning nil or not the correct VC. Look at the edit.

Comment: When you're doing this, are you updating views on other tabs?

Comment: @pbush25 No, I only try to update a UILabel in the same tab.

Comment: Why not just use self then?

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately can't see anything wrong with your code, logically it should be working. Possibly your data source is being updated after reloadData is being called, although considering the cleanliness of your code I doubt that is the case.

I would try the following pattern, if only to see if the code in your answer is in fact faulty.

In SecondViewController's viewDidLoad:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reloadTableView:", name: "reloadSecondVCTableView", object: nil)
```

And in the body:

```
func reloadTableView(_: NSNotification) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And after the second if statement in your posted code send the notification :

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("reloadSecondVCTableView", object: nil)
```

Comment: Ah, damn! Hmm, the issue must be elsewhere then, how are you updating the data source for your tableView?

Comment: Maybe print the dataSource after its initially loaded and then again in your code above to check if it has changed before reloadData is called